# Thinking in C++ shift operators

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I'm reading through a book on C++ standards: "Thinking in C++" by Bruce Eckel.

A lot of the C++ features are explained really well in this book but I have come to a brick wall on something and whether it may or may not help me when I wish to program a game for example, it's irking me as to how it works and I really cannot get it from the explanation given.

I was wondering if anybody here could help me in explaining how this example program actually works:

printBinary.h -

```
void printBinary(const unsigned char val);
```

printBinary.cpp -

```
#include <iostream>

void printBinary(const unsigned char val) {
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (val & ( 1 << i)) 
            std::cout << "1";
        else 
            std::cout << "0"; 
    }
}
```

Bitwise.cpp -

```
#include "printBinary.h" 
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

#define PR(STR, EXPR) \ 
cout << STR; printBinary(EXPR); cout << endl; 

int main() {

    unsigned int getval; 
    unsigned char a, b; 
    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 255: ";
    cin >> getval; a = getval; 
    PR ("a in binary: ", a);
    cin >> getval; b = getval; 
    PR ("b in binary: ", b); 
    PR("a | b = ", a | b);
```

This program is supposed to explain to me how the shift bitwise operator (<<) and (>>) work but I simply don't get it, I mean sure I know how it works using cin and cout but am I stupid for not understanding this?

this piece in particular confuses me more so than the rest:

```
if (val & ( 1 << i))
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: How deep do you understand binary representation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (val & ( 1 << i))
```

Consider the following binary number (128):

`10000000`

`&` is bitwise "AND" - `0 & 0 = 0`, `0 & 1 = 1 & 0 = 0`, `1 & 1 = 1`.

`<<` is bitwise shift operator; it shifts the binary representation of the shifted number to left.

`00000001 << 1 = 00000010`; `00000001 << 2 = 00000100`.

Write it down on a piece of paper in all iterations and see what comes out.

Comment: `&&` is "logical and", `&` is "bitwise and".

Comment: I don't mean to ask further questions and this explanation is really good, but how is the compiler looking at "val" in "if (val & (1 << i))". Let's say val is 65 which means as a char being passed to the function it would be "A". What is the compiler looking at val as being?

Comment: `65` is `01000001` (2 ^ 6 + 2 ^ 0 = 64 + 1 = 65), if that's what you are asking about.

Comment: So if statement is looking at it in its binary form when it is performing boolean algebra?

Comment: Well, _bitwise_, not _boolean_ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
1 << i
```

takes the `int`-representation of `1` and shifts it `i` bits to the left.

```
val & x
```

is a bit-wise `AND` between `val` and `x` (where `x` is `1 << i` in this example).

```
if(x)
```

tests if `x` converted to `bool` is true. Any non-zero value of an integral type converted to `bool` is true.

Answer (score 0):

<< has two different meanings in the code you shown.

```
if (val & (1 << i))
```

<< is used to bitshift, so the value 1 will be shifted left by i bits

```
cout << ....
```

The stream class overloads the operator <<, so here it has a different meaning than before.
In this case, << is a function that outputs the contents on its right to cout

Answer (score 0):

```
if (val & ( 1 << i))
```

This checks if the bit in i-th position is set. (1 << i) is something like 000001000 for i = 3. Now if the & operation returns non-zero, that means val had the corresponding bit set.